# Global variable not defined across multiple useEffects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

I'm trying to setup a Mapbox which flies to different locations based on Redux state. I am using two useEffects: the first to render the map, and the second to flyTo the location based on a state change. I am doing this so the map isn't rerendered every state change, which prevents a smooth flyTo animation. I have attempted to declare a global map variable outside of the useEffects to give it global scope but upon state change, the map variable from the second useEffect is undefined.

I am having trouble finding a way to allow the map location to be updated without rerendering the entire map. I thought a second useEffect would do the trick but this globally declared variable isn't working, and I'm not exactly sure why.

```
const Map = (props) => {
    
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';

    const mapContainer = useRef(null);

    let map;

    useEffect(() => {

        map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapContainer.current
        });

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {

        map.flyTo({
            center: [
                props.map.lng,
                props.map.lat
            ]
        })

        map.zoom = props.map.zoom;

        new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(props.map).addTo(map);

    }, [props.map]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={mapContainer} className={styles.mapContainer}/>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        map: state.map
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Map);
```

Comment: Make map a state hook using useState and always map and sync your props with your state. and rest of the things are same.

Comment: You can also use https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` is redeclared each render cycle, thus undefined when not set by the first effect. Use a ref to store the `map` as well. Remember to access via `map.current` to get the current value of the ref.

```
const Map = (props) => {
    
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';

    const mapContainer = useRef(null);
    const map = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {

        map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapContainer.current
        });

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {

        map.current.flyTo({
            center: [
                props.map.lng,
                props.map.lat
            ]
        })

        map.current.zoom = props.map.zoom;

        new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(props.map).addTo(map.current);

    }, [props.map]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={mapContainer} className={styles.mapContainer}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I didn't realize useRef could be used for creating mutable global variables like that. Will do some reading on it.

Comment: @FRMR It's meant for nearly literally ***ANYTHING*** you want to hold on to between render cycles. Don't use it for anything you *want to trigger a render* though.